# Fetch site data to Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example [post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/JNfDAOxo60Y).  I want to use IMPORTXML function to fetch data to a spreadsheet. I tried numerous permutations and combinations but I just can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I am doing:

I right clicked on the Experts name, went to inspect and copied the XPath which came out to be:

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h3/span`
```

I am using this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/JNfDAOxo60Y","https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/JNfDAOxo60Y")
```

but I always end up getting this error:

> Imported Xml content can not be parsed.

Can anyone please help me?

I've never used this function and I have no idea what xml is that's why I can't seem to solve it by myself.

Comment: It looks like the page isn't valid XML, so you won't be able to use XPath (and `ImportXML`) to pull data out of it.

Comment: I found a video link on youtube which makes it seem so simple but I can't replicate it on google forum website. If somebody could understand it please help:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZ44kAeiOo

Comment: @Steve any idea how can I accomplish it then?

Comment: The problem here is that I'm doing a project for work. I can not use any third party addons or extension. I need to accomplish this either using sheets formulas or google apps scripts. So fat, I've tried all IMPORT XML/Feed/HTML but no success. If anyone could point me in the right direction then I can get back to you with my research and questions.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML is able to read the source code retrieved by the specified URL in contrast with a web browser that shows a rendered webpage.

In this case the name of the expert is not included on the source code returned by `https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/JNfDAOxo60Y`, it's added by the [browser's rendering engine](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_rendering_engine).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Any idea how I can accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: "I follow Google Drive Help Forum and there are certain topics which are really like and would like to know if there's a new response on them" -> Subscribe to those topics that you want to follow. Perhaps, the easiest way is to subscribe to the forum and use email filters to keep those that you want to follow and delete the others. Also you could try to use an RSS feeds aggregator or to create a chrome extension.

Comment: By googling a bit I found this: [This Extension Helps You Follow Google Product Forum Threads Easily](https://www.chromestory.com/2015/04/this-extension-helps-you-follow-google-product-forum-threads-easily/)

Comment: The problem here is that I'm doing a project for work. I can not use any third party addons or extension. I need to accomplish this either using sheets formulas or google apps scripts. So fat, I've tried all IMPORT XML/Feed/HTML but no success. If anyone could point me in the right direction then I can get back to you with my research and questions.